# How to calculate the numbers from different gameObjects together in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unityscript

I'm building a Unity game where you have feelers, and by clicking the color given at that moment, you can get or lose a score, time or you get a game over screen.

My problem is - I have a lot gameObjects and each one calculates scores alone, (eache one have his own score int) and I need one code detects all scores number one, so I can see the scores one point (about how to see it, this is less important).

The name of the number that I want to find is called (how creative): score.
And yes, this is a **public float**.

I am most glad if I could write this document duration (unless you have no choice anyway ...)

sorry about any grammar mistakes, I do my best.

Thanks from advance
Roei Meiri.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I can't image this would be very efficient, you would probably get better performance if you keep you own list of all the scoring objects(add to the list when creating the scoring object).

That being said...(uncompiled example).
Assuming you want to find of all objects with a particular component, like

```
class ScoringObject:Monobehavior
```

then you can find them all and add up the scores like so...

```
float totalscore=0;
ScoringObject[] listOfScores= Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(ScoringObject)) as ScoringObject[];
foreach (ScoringObject scorObject in listOfScores) {
            totalscore+=listOfScores.score;}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html